# How to rebuild image after rotate anti-clockwise

Tags: winrt-xaml

Problem : 
I rotate the landscape image anti clockwise 1 times at 90degree. After rebuilding the image, it does not look it has been rotated 1 times in anti clockwise position. It provides clockwise 90 degrees image.

I used below code :

```
 var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, fileStream);

  encoder.SetPixelData(
  BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
  BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
  (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
  (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
   DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
   DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
   pixelBuffer.ToArray());

   encoder.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise90Degrees;

    await encoder.FlushAsync();

There is no AntiClockwise90Degrees in BitmapRotation
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BitmapRotation.Clockwise90Degrees will rotate 90° clockwise.
BitmapRotation.Clockwise270Degrees will rotate 90° anticlockwise (360° - 90° = 270°)